# Javascript - How to squared a number?

Tags: javascript, 32-bit

Using the javascript function

```
function squareIt(number) {
   return number * number;
}
```

When given the number 4294967296 the function returns 18446744073709552000 is returned

Everyone knows the real answer is 18446744073709551616 :-)

I guess this is to to with rounding on my 32-bit machine. However, would this script give the right answer on a 64 bit machine? Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ChrisV- [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-to). Also it easier for people to evaluate your question by typing the following JavaScript directly into the browser URL textbox:

```
javascript:4294967296*4294967296
```

Answer (score 2):

what about this

```
function squareIt(number){
return Math.pow(number,2)
}
```

Comment: um, did you bother testing it? You would know the answer.

Comment: yeah, and it returns 18446744073709552000

Answer (score 1):

Javascript uses 64 bit floating point arithmetic internally for numerical calculations - the results you see are a reflection of  this, and will happene regardless of the underlying architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more example based on **[BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js#square)**.

```js
alert(bigInt(4294967296).square());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/big-integer/1.6.40/BigInteger.min.js"></script>
```